# facebook automated authorization / login

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization

there is an facebook application, you can see it there:
http://www.facebook.com/tdmtravelclub?v=app_197602066931325&app_data=wlbb%3D1
You have to like it and than you can play a game (you don't have to i just explain the functionality of it).

This application isn't forcing you to login (i think the authorization is automated), but they can query the user data (they see if you liked the site).

I lookd for a similar authenthication method for fb apps but i didn't found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you know about a user (who has not authorised your application) within a tab application is if he is a fan or not. Facebook sends this information via the signed request.

- [PHP SDK Demystified – What is Signed Request?](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/blog/2011/php-sdk-demystified-%E2%80%93-what-is-a-signed-request/)
- [Authentication within a Page Tab](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/)
- [SO Question including signed request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143468/facebook-facebook-getsignedrequest-error)